# Using strsplit ON a list in R

Tags: r, text-mining

Consider the following exerpt from a list called **matches**:

```
[[9997]]
[1] "20070125" "11"      

[[9998]]
[1] "20070129" "01"      

[[9999]]
[1] "20070129" "02"      

[[10000]]
[1] "20070129" "03"
```

The `class` of this list is obviously `list`. I know that `strsplit` requires a vector input.

I want to use `strsplit` to try to get only the date, not the second number.

```
strsplit(as.character(matches)," ")[10000]
```

This returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "c(\"20070129\"," "\"03\")"
```

Instead of

```
[[1]]
[1] "20070129" 
[2] "03"
```

As I had hoped. I am not sure what the problem is as I tried to coerce the list into a character vector.

Here is code you can use to generate the example above:

```
matches<-vector("list", 10000)
matches[[10000]] <- paste(c("20070129","03"))
```

perhaps there are alternatives to strsplit that can be used on a list?

Comment: Try `lapply(matches, "[", 1)`

Comment: Use `lapply`. Coercing lists to character (intentionally or not) is one of my all time favorite R brain twisters.

Comment: @akrun,, my goodness that worked. Though I still don't know why

Comment: I tagged it as a dupe.  Please go through the link.